# How to develop a quiz based android application

Tags: android, mysql

I'm developing an android application which is an objective type,In my app there are 4 subjects like C,C++,Java,Android,Users should select the subject of their own choice for example If users selected Android it will load Android Chapters from chapters topics should be loaded and now they should take a quiz on that particular topic till here I have done and its working fine, Now I need to store the questions and answers in mysql database and I should retrieve them according to the topic wise. How to load the questions and answers from database and a topic may contain more than 10 questions How to validate them and show the score to the user?

Comment: We're not going to write your app for you.  Come back here with specific questions on individual parts of the app and you may be on topic.

Comment: @GabeSechan Actually I explained the scenario.I need only how to load question based on topic..

Comment: *"SELECT question, answer FROM table_name WHERE topic='Android'"* and for validate `if(user_answer.equals(answer)){...}`

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira How to load 10 questions one after another after answering and finally should show the result

Comment: use a button to click or view to swipe between questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use web service to connect to your mysql DB using ajax and json/xml data format. query the data from DB and output the data using JSON/XML. parse the JSON/XML data and display in your content.

Comment: yeah I'm using web service only but my issue is how to load 10 questions one after another in the same activity?